# bind datagrid with form

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid in a user control and I can populate the datagrid with different objects programmatically depending on the type of object I have different columns number.
When I select a element, I want to do a bind to populate other user control with the different data that is a form with textbox. But I don't have a property to do the bind and I don't know how to do.

**MainWindow**

```
<window ...
xmlns:gf="clr-namespace:GenericForms"/>
<gf:TypePanel x:Name="myTypePanel" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" InnerValue="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myTypeGrid}"/>
<gf:TypeGrid x:Name="myTypeGrid" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

**TypeGrid**

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ThisControl,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single"/>
    </Grid>
```

**TypePanel**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="root">
</StackPanel>
```

The type panel is fill with a method in function the object

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InnerValue", typeof(Object), typeof(TypePanel));


public Object InnerValue
{
    get { return (Object)GetValue(InnerValueProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(InnerValueProperty, value);
        if (value == InnerValue)
        {
            UpdateBindings();
         }
    }
    }
```

The type grid is fill with array objects:

```
foreach (var item in innerFields)
{
    column.Binding = new Binding(item.Key) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}

            /* add items rows */
foreach (var item in innerValues)
{
    dataGrid.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Just one of many simple workarounds - Just pass the data you want the other form to represent via the new form's constructor. Handle the population of the that new forms controls from there.

Comment: If I selected a item, how I can pass the data to the constructor through a bind

Comment: Just get the cell values, row index, pass the entire row, do a fetch based on a key, pass the first form itself and select the values as needed. Hell you can even pass the binding source and just select the values from there. Google my friend, powerful tool.